# Can I pass data directly between Cassini webserver and hosted ASP.NET child app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I've got an application which for various reasons, has been created as a "website on CD" project. It uses Cassini as the webserver (running as a thread inside the main app) and a C# .NET browser application (which uses the WebBrowserEx control).

The application now has to use a barcode scanner which I cannot easily interface with from within the ASP.NET part of the app, so I was thinking of using a normal WinForms dialog for the barcode scanner, but then I need to pass the data to the ASP.NET app.

How can I do this?

I realise I could put the scanned barcodes in the URL (as CSV) but this seems a bit messy. Is there a way I can directly insert data into the ASP.NET session, or directly call methods in the hosted ASP.NET application or is this not possible? I'm just trying to think of the cleanest way to pass the data back to the ASP.NET app...

Answer (score 0):

Add a WCF Service to the ASP.NET app, and consume it in the Forms App.